# Integração projeto asp net mvc com sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

Como posso fazer a conexão do visual studio com o sql server galera? Fiz uma tela de cadastro, mas não faço idéia de como posso fazer com que meu site mande esses dados pro sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, boa tarde!

Segue um tutorial em português da próxima Microsoft que vai te ajudar passo a passo como fazer o que precisa.

[Tutorial: Introdução ao EF Core em um aplicativo Web ASP.NET MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score -2):

O EF (Entity Framework) Core é uma versão leve, extensível, de software livre e multiplataforma da popular tecnologia de acesso a dados do Entity Framework.

EF Core pode servir como um mapeador relacional de objeto (O/RM), que:

Permite que os desenvolvedores do .NET trabalhem com um banco de dados usando objetos .NET.
Elimina a necessidade da maior parte do código de acesso a dados que normalmente precisa ser gravado.
O EF Core é compatível com vários mecanismos de banco de dados, consulte detalhes em Provedores de Banco de Dados.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).